# React reducer - data.map is not a function or how to add values to case in a reducer

Tags: reactjs, use-context, use-reducer

I have this reducer:

```
export const reducer = ( state, { type, payload } ) => {

      switch ( type ) {
        case 'SET_TOURS_IN_CART':
          return { ...state, toursInCart: payload };
        default:
          return state;
      }
    };
```

I want to add data to this reducer using `SET_TOURS_IN_CART` dispatch.

the payload contains this data: `{id: '3', name: 'Best of Salzburg & Vienna in 8 Days Tour'}`

I want the `toursInCart` to contain an array of objects, so that each time I add a new payload the array will add the new object to the existing data.

this is the provider:

```
import React, { useReducer, createContext } from 'react'
import { reducer } from './cart-context-reducer'

export const CartContext = createContext();

export default function CartContextProvider( props ) {
  const initialState = {
      toursInCart: []
    },
    [ data, dispatch ] = useReducer( reducer, initialState );

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={ { data, dispatch } }>
      { props.children }
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: not an answer, just to avoid some errors.
 `export const reducer = ( state = {}, { type, payload } ) => {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return an object, not an array: `return { ...state, toursInCart: payload };` (the `toursInCart: payload` part)

If you want to add the `payload` to the array `toursInCart`,
try:

```
return {...state, toursInCart: [...state.toursInCart, payload]}
```

Or any variant